# Cannot connect Airpods to 19.04 as Headset; can connect as Headphones

Tags: bluetooth, 19.04, bluez

With Ubuntu 19.04, I try to connect some Airpods using Bluetooth. For that I've installed:

```
Package: bluez
Architecture: amd64
Version: 5.50-0ubuntu2
Multi-Arch: foreign
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Bluetooth team <ubuntu-bluetooth@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Bluetooth Maintainers <pkg-bluetooth-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 4625
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8), libreadline8 (>= 6.0), libudev1 (>= 196), kmod, udev (>= 170-1), lsb-base, dbus
Conflicts: bluez-alsa, bluez-audio (<= 3.36-3), bluez-utils (<= 3.36-3)
Breaks: udev (<< 170-1)
Replaces: bluez-alsa, bluez-audio (<= 3.36-3), bluez-input, bluez-network, bluez-serial, bluez-utils (<= 3.36-3), udev (<< 170-1)
Filename: pool/main/b/bluez/bluez_5.50-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
Size: 955664
MD5sum: 9f5eaa3bf6987fe5b61f6fd3bfc52a7c
SHA1: 23fae2727d17127439655a5ed203878b949a6d0d
SHA256: b892593447f91da4bfbfa5989af35934f23278aabc6e95460bb262742742a164
Homepage: http://www.bluez.org
Description-en: Bluetooth tools and daemons
 This package contains tools and system daemons for using Bluetooth devices.
 .
 BlueZ is the official Linux Bluetooth protocol stack. It is an Open Source
 project distributed under GNU General Public License (GPL).
Description-md5: ef25d6a9f4a57e78f32faa7b58ef4e59
Task: ubuntu-desktop-minimal, ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, kubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop-core, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-desktop
Supported: 9m
```

Already tried to set ControllerMode = bredr (also tried with dual). All I succeed is to use the Airpods as Headphones. 
When trying to change the profile to Headset Head Unit for using also the microphone I got

```
Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit
```

How may I resolve this?